# problem with opengles2 and gingerbread on galaxy s

Tags: android, galaxy, depth-buffer

Has anyone experienced a change in depth sort behaviour after upgrading a galaxy s to android 2.3.3 ?

I am finding that the depth sort fails to work once a certain polycount threshold has been reached.

Scenes that worked fine on 2.2 now are failing to sort.

Anyone have any info on this? Nothing comes up when I google.

Answer (score 1):

Could be, I'm having an issue with the depth buffer on S2 (running Gingerbread) whereas I don't have any issues on 2.2.

EDIT: Solved the problem, it turns out that for some reason 2.2+ do not like -ve depth buffer near values. Try keeping it all positive and it should resolve itself.